# PyQt4 multithreading using QThread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt4, qthread

There is an endless block when `xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring()` function is called in the `QThread`. Also lots of other calls makes the QThread blocked like `multiprocessing.Process()`.
Important to say that it is a pure block, no exception or break.

Here is the code (a little edited but same principle as the source):

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from Ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
import sys
import xml.etree

class Bruton(QThread):
    def __init__(self, mw):
        super(Bruton, self).__init__(mw) 
        self.mw = mw

    def run(self):
        print("This message I see.")
        tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring("<element>text</element>")
        print("But this one never.")

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.init_bruton()

    # When the form is shown...
    def showEvent(self, arg1):
        self.bruton.start()

    def init_bruton(self):
        self.bruton = Bruton(self)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mw = MainWindow()
mw.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Can you post the code? I can read code better than English describing it ;)

Comment: Are you sure it is blocking as opposed to throwing an exception?

Comment: @Judge: As I said in the first line, there is no exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I've shown here is shortened (the source is divided to two files and `__ini__.py`). I noticed that the main module must be the module that starts the `QApplication`. So I added `app.exec_()` to the `__init__.py` which is the main module of my program.

Answer (score 2):

The code as posted doesn't actually run, but with a couple minor changes it runs and works fine. Here is the code with modifications:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree

class Bruton(QThread):
    def __init__(self, mw):
        super(Bruton, self).__init__(mw)
        self.mw = mw

    def run(self):
        print("This message I see.")
        tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring("<element>text</element>")
        print("But this one never.")

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.init_bruton()

    # When the form is shown...
    def showEvent(self, arg1):
        self.bruton.start()

    def init_bruton(self):
        self.bruton = Bruton(self)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mw = MainWindow()
mw.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And here is the output:

```
$ python test.py 
This message I see.
But this one never.
```

This is with Python 2.6.6, PyQt4 4.8.3, on Debian Unstable.

Can you try it in your environment and see if my modified example works for you? If so, you are on the road to a solution for your real code. =)